# Get only part of file using sed or awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file which contains text as follows:

```
Directory /home/user/ "test_user"
bunch of code
another bunch of code
```

How can I get from this file only the `/home/user/` part?

I've managed to use `awk -F '"' 'NR==1{print $1}' file.txt` to get rid of rest of the file and I'm gettig output like this:

`Directory /home/user/`

How can I change this command to get only `/home/user/` part? I'd like to make it as simple as possible. Unfortunately, I can't modify this file to add/change the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk` it should be:

```
awk 'NR==1{print $2}' file.txt
```

Setting the field delimiter to `"` was wrong Since it splits the line into these fields:

```
$1 = 'Directory /home/user/'
$2 = 'test_user'
$3 = '' (empty)
```

The default record separator, which is `[[:space:]]+`, splits like this:

```
$1 = 'Directory'
$2 = '/home/user/'
$3 = '"test_user"'
```

Answer (score 5):

this should work the fastest, noticeable if your file is large

```
awk '{print $2; exit}' file
```

it will print the second field of the first line and stop processing the rest of the file.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate, you can use `head` and `cut`:

```
$ head -n 1 file | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using the `-F"` as that changes the delimiter.  If you remove that, then `$2` will get you what you want.

```
awk 'NR==1{print $2}' file.txt
```

You can also use `awk` to execute the `print` when the line contains `/home/user` instead of counting records:

```
awk '/\home\/user\//{print $2}' file.txt
```

In this case, if the line were buried in the file, or if you had multiple instances, you would get the name for every occurrence wherever it was.

Answer (score -3):

Adding some grep

```
grep Directory file.txt|awk '{print $2}'
```

Comment: `grep` is superfluous since awk can search for a pattern. Use `awk '/Directory/{print $2}'`